# Ubuntu port forwarding, Desktop 64bit, wifi, raspberry pi 4 B 8 gb

Tags: server, raspberrypi, port-forwarding

I have come across a problem while using Ubuntu 64bit desktop for raspberry pi.
I would like to use my raspberry pi 4 as a Minecraft server, having completed the server set up, I am able to get a server running on my local network.
**The problem**
When I attempt to connect to my server from another computer it does not allow me to.
**Self-Diagnosed**
set the wifi setting in ip4 to a static ip
write in ip such as                    192.168.1.73
submask                                24
gateway                                I use the default from my router

use "ufw" to allow port 25565
sudo ufw enable 25565/tcp

change router setting to allow ip and port 25565/tcp in port forwarding

At the end of the day nothing seemed to work.
I keep opening transmission to test if port 25565 is open in nothing work. I can't seem to assign a static ip without using Netplan; the gui settings does not work it seems, and there is not setup I can find for wifi that give me a static Ip

I would appreciate any solutions anyone might have?

Comment: Put the client and server on the same LAN. Can the client successfully ping the server?

Comment: Yes the client can ping the server, Do I have to use a LAN connection?

Comment: A LAN connection is the easiest way (by far) to troubleshoot what the problem is and where the problem might be -- it removes the router as a variable. Half the time the problem is a router setting or a faulty router (that happens), half the time it's not. When both are on the LAN, can the Minecraft Client successfully connect to the Minecraft Server? If not, what is the complete error?

Comment: Is there a crash course I could take to learn more about routers. I feel frustrated because I have some basic understanding of linux and I should be able to port this out but the commands I have tried don't seem to effect the tcp port at all.

Comment: Don't assume that it's the router. Don't assume that it's your learning curve. Perhaps..but perhaps not. Methodically reduce complexity so you are dealing with fewer variables. Don't jump to conclusions; some problems can be really weird and convoluted. Don't assume that all problems are software; hardware gets faults, too. And don't forget to reboot *everything* a couple times.

Comment: I appreciate you response. I have reset the router, reset firewall, allowed tcp port 25565 with port forwarding. The router I am using is the T3200M. it has port forwarding functionality.